# :active pseudoclass with animations sometimes prevents postbacks in Chrome and IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

Has anyone else ran into this issue? I have a web forms site and I wanted to add an :active pseudo class to a link button, basically to animate it before doing some action. However, for some reason that I cannot figure out, animations in the :active state *sometimes* prevent a postback (other times it posts back just fine). Other effects (ie not animations or transformations) work just fine. So, this works just fine, EVERY time:

```
.mylinkbuttonclass:active
{
    width:75%;
}
```

Whereas the following only causes a postback about 40-50% of the time. The other times there is no postback at all (I put breakpoints in my page load and prerender events which never get hit)

```
.mylinkbuttonclass:active
{
    animation: flip 200ms linear 1;
    -moz-animation: flip 200ms linear 1;
    -o-animation: flip 200ms linear 1;
    -ms-animation: flip 200ms linear 1;
    -webkit-animation: flip 200ms linear 1;  
}

@keyframes flip{
    0% {
       transform:  rotateY(0deg);
    }
    50% 
    {
        opacity: 0.10;
        transform:  rotateY(180deg); 
    }
    100% {
       transform:  rotateY(180deg); 
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens, or how to fix it? I didn`t think it was possible for a pseudo class to prevent a postback! On the times where the postback fails, the animation still runs just fine; there is just no postback to the server.

Edit: Haven`t tested on Firefox yet but the failure is reproducible on both Chrome and IE 11.

Edit2: Wow so this actually works really well in Firefox; it`s Chrome and IE that have the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am a bit short on time on this one I ended up simply changing the link button class on button click to a new class which contains the animation. It works 100% of the time on all 3 major browsers but I would love to hear if anyone knows why it doesn`t work with the :active selector